# Properties of the quadratic form for the sum of the Jacobian and its transpose

Tags: dynamical-systems, quadratic-forms, jacobian

Consider the Jacobian matrix of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
f_{1}(x_1(t), x_2(t),\;\; \ldots \;\;x_{N_1}(t))\\
\vdots \\
f_{N_2}(x_1(t), x_2(t),\;\; \ldots \;\;x_{N_1}(t))
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let the jacobian matrix be denoted by $\mathbf{J}$
and let all the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{J}$ be negative.

consider the symmetric matrix
$$
\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{J} + \mathbf{J}^\intercal
$$

What can we say about the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$? Will they all be negative?

Also, consider a non-zero vector $\mathbf{x}$
What can we say about the sign of:
$$ \mathbf{x^\intercal A x}$$
Will it always be negative?

A [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709480/linear-stability-analysis-of-a-dynamical-systems-based-only-on-symmetric-part-of/4526477#4526477) with no answers yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

$$J=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 5\\0 & -2\end{bmatrix}.$$

We have that

$$A:=J+J^T=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 5\\5 & -4\end{bmatrix}$$

which is not negative definite.

As a result, it is not possible to provide a general statement that if $J$ is Hurwitz stable, then $J+J^T$ is negative definite. The structure of the matrix here will play an essential role.

Comment: are there any conditions under which we can say that $A$ will have all eigenvalues negative? Also could you have a look at the linked question on dynamical systems? The reasoning in that post seems right to me but it is contrary to your answer. What is wrong there.

Comment: Yes, but they are highly matrix dependent and since you do not provide more information about your matrix $J$, it is not really possible to be more specific.

Comment: There are no more conditions on J. Where can I find such condition-dependent properties? Could you provide sources?

Comment: If you have no condition on $J$ besides that $J$ is stable, there is no condition for what you are looking for, as demonstrated by my counterexample.

Comment: could you link to sources based on which you said: "highly matrix dependent"? Where can I find these conditions?

Comment: I do not have such sources. I am speaking by experience. There are very simple conditions but they are most of the time useless as they assume very simple matrix structures. The issue is that no properties are really preserved from $J$ to $J+J^T$ in the general case.

Comment: thanks a lot! Could you please answer the linked question as well?